# Adding HTML/Images etc into WordPress Menu

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem in the WordPress menu. I need to add some additional HTML or images or any custom text. Currently I am using jQuery to append to Menu item's submenus `<ul>`. I am currently using this static method, but I want it to be dynamic.

[Here is what I want.](http://www.wimbledon.com/index.html) Like how they have images and text in submenus.

Please guide me on how to have it dynamic in `wp_nav_menu()`.

Answer (score 0):

considering the default wp nav menu is rather limited when it comes to design options, the only possibility in my opinion is implementing a custom menu walker. some good starting info on that topic can be found here: http://jamescollings.co.uk/blog/wordpress-custom-walker-output-section-of-menu/
using this approach you can still manage your menu structure with wordpress standard tools, but have a lot more freedom when it comes to layouting the output.

another approach would be using some extended menu plugins like for example http://wpmegamenu.com/